# Is 'what for' identical to'why'

Tags: interrogatives

> (1) I wondered **what she was crying for**.
>   (2) I wondered **why she was crying**.

Are (1) and (2) exchangeable? Is 'what for' identical to ‘why’ in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are interchangeable:

[what ... for?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-for)
​

> why:
>
> - What did you do that for?
> - What are you emptying that cupboard for?

(Collins)

Answer (score 0):

In informal use, one is commonly exchanged with the other. In that context, they are interchangeable.

---

However, they are not actually identical in more formal use or syntactical analysis.

> ***Why*** was she crying?
>   She *(dropped an ice cream cone on the sidewalk)*.

When asking *why*, you are asking about the *overall situation* that has caused someone to cry.

> *What* was she crying ***for***?
>   *(The ice cream cone)* that she'd dropped on the sidewalk.

When asking *what for*, you can also be specifically asking about the *object* of a person's sadness. With the preposition, you could be considered to be crying *on behalf of* somebody or something. (The priceless and irreplaceable vase that was broken or the child who was injured.)

---

Although the answer may be the same in each case (somebody might reply to my second example question with my first example answer), there is still a distinction that can be made in terms of the grammar used.

Comment: I think both are asking for the reason for her tears.   *What was she crying for? --The baby bit her.*  Not that **cry for** doesn't have another meaning, as in *to cry for help*.